# Join together 3 entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have the following entities:

**Person.java**

```
@Table(name = persons)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "UserID", nullable = false) 
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "Employeenumber", nullable = false) private String employeeNumber;
    @Column(name = "Firstname", nullable = false) private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "Lastname", nullable = false) private String lastName;

    public User() { }

    public User(String employeeNumber, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();

        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /*
        getter and setters

        ...
    */

}
```

**Personhistory.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = personhistory)
public class Personhistory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UserID", nullable = false) 
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "Fromdate", nullable = false) private Date fromDate;
    @Column(name = "Todate", nullable = false) private Date toDate;
    @Column(name = "TeamID", nullable = false) private Integer teamId;


    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "UnikId", nullable = false) 
    private Integer unikId;

    public Userhistory() {

    }


    public Userhistory(Long userId, Date fromDate, Date toDate, int teamId) {
        super();

        this.userId = userId;
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.teamId = teamId;
    }

    /*
        Getters and setters

        ...
    */

}
```

**Team.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TeamID") 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int teamId;

    @Column(name = "TeamNumber") private String teamNumber;

    public Team() {}

    public Team(String teamNumber) {
        super();
        this.teamNumber = teamNumber;
    }

    /*
        Getters and setters

        ...
    */

}
```

I want to make a API call like this:

```
localhost:8080/users/{employee}
```

And get back an object containing the person (His emp-number, firstname and lastname), when he was at the team and what team that is.

If I were to write this query in MSSQL, it would look like this:

```
select * from persons p

join personhistory ph on ph.UserID = p.UserID
    and ph.Fromdate <= cast(getdate() as date)
    and ph.Todate >= cast(getdate() as date)
join team t on t.TeamID = ph.TeamID

where u.Employeenumber = '999'
```

I have searched around for different solutions like HQL, JPQL, Criteria and so on, but I'm unable to make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Hibernate 5.1 provides more generic joins but with prior versions you'd either have to use a cross join and add the conditions in the where-clause or provide a real relation between the entities and join on that relation (using the "with" keyword for additional join conditions).

Example (note that I left out many annotations for simplicity):

```
class Person {      
  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "user" )
  Collection<Personhistory> history;

  ...
}

class Personhistory {
  @ManyToOne
  Person user;

  @ManyToOne
  Team team;

  ...
}
```

Then the query could become

```
select p, ph, t from Person p 
  join p.history ph with ph.fromdate <= :date and ph.toDate >= :date
  join ph.team t
  where p.employeeNumber = :number
```

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a go.